# How to not override a val of a parent class?

Tags: scala, inheritance

please take a look at the following code:

```
scala> sealed abstract class Person(val name: String)
defined class Person

scala> case class Student(id: Int, name: String) extends Person(name)
<console>:8: error: overriding value name in class Person of type String;
value name needs `override' modifier
       case class Student(id: Int, name: String) extends Person(name)
                                   ^
```

This might be a trivial question, but after searching the web for quite some time, I wasn't able to figure out how to simply pass the string that `Student`'s constructor will be provided as `name` to the `Person`'s constructor. I don't want to override anything. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Perhaps you intend: `sealed trait Person { def name: String }` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All constructor parameters of a case class are `val`s. That's the whole point. Roughly speaking, it is what gives you the ability to enjoy the benefits cases classes provide compared to regular classes: copying, extraction, pattern matching, etc.

If you want `Student` to be a case class, you *should* override `name`. Theoretically, you can avoid overriding it by giving the val a different name: `case class Student(id: Int, studentName: String) extends Person(studentName)` - this works, but just doesn't make very much sense - you end up having two different member vals whose values are always identical.

Alternatively, if there is an actual *reason* why you don't want to override `name` (I can't imagine what one could possibly be, but if ...), then `Student` should not be a case class: `class Student(val id: Int, name: String) extends Person(name)`.

Comment: The first paragraph is quite misleading. If it were correct, non-`case` classes whose constructor parameters are `val`s (e.g. `class Student(val id: Int, val name: String)`) would enjoy the same benefits. They don't.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov "Brain is what gives humans the ability to engage in pointless arguments about semantics". Would you argue, that this statement is " quite misleading" too, because rats have brains but do not argue semantics? :)